# rails 3 relative url root not being used in links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I have a rails 3.0.1 app hosted on `www.example.com/v1` using Phusion Passenger. In my config, I have the following:

```
ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] = "/v1"
```

The rails apps is loading fine. The issue is with the links on the page. Whenever I use `link_to` with "/some_path" as the URL, the final url is `www.example.com/some_path` when it should be `www.example.com/v1/some_path`.

Why is `link_to` not recognizing my relative url root and incorporating it when generating links? How do I get around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've never done my routes like this before. Try this in your `routes.rb` file:

```
scope "v1" do
  resources :some_resource
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use link_to without starting slash

```
link_to "some_path"
```

Another way to deal with relative routes on client side is to use **base** tag

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://example.com/current/opened/page">
```